# how to use variable immediately after it's defined - js

Tags: javascript, function, dom

How, sorry for this weird title, i didn't know how to put this... Here my explanation:

I have a function where I define variable (I'm looping over an array and if condition is matched, I define let). It works everytime item.dataset.category changes, so after every scroll.

After the loop, I call another function, where I use this variable as an argument. In the second function I use it to check if another condition is matched:

```
//first function
    const getDataset = (e) => {
      let dataset;
      const cat = Array.from(categories.children);
      cat.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.className.includes('active')) {
          dataset = item.dataset.category;
        }
        
      });
         changeNavActive(dataset);
    };
    
//second function
    const changeNavActive = (dataset) => {
      const navItems = Array.from(navList.children);
      navItems.forEach((item) => {
        item.classList.remove('active');
        if (item.dataset.category === dataset) {
          item.classList.add('active');
        }
      });
    };
```

It's not working and I think I understand why - callign of second function is at the same time as declaring variable, so I geting this let in the next call. The result is that second function works with delay of one scroll.

This is a function which calls getDataset():

```
const scrollRows = (e) => {
  if (window.scrollY > slider.clientHeight) {
    e.deltaY > 0 ? move++ : move--;
    getDataset();
    if (move > categories.children.length - 1)
      move = categories.children.length - 1;
  }
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Do you really want to call `changeNavActive()` inside the loop? Until the `if` doesn't set value of `dataset`, it's going to be repeatedly called with `undefined`, and after that it will get repeatedly called with that single(?) item. By the way: you can debug code in browsers, visit the developer console tab called "sources", and put some breakpoints here and there.

Comment: which variable specifically? Also can you provide more code or better yet a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @tevemadar - right, I've called it in the wrong place. I've changed code, no should be ok. Still not working.

Comment: @sample let dataset

Comment: can you also include the code the causes the loop? (Ie. This bit: "It works everytime item.dataset.category changes, so after every scroll"

Comment: @sample done :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but can you also define `navList`,  `categories`,  and `category`? Thanks